# route to different page than show in a link_to destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In an index view (a list of attachments for a task), I have a link to destroy (delete) a record (attachment).  It automatically goes to the /attachments (show) page after the delete.  I would like it to just refresh the page the link_to code is on.

Here is the code in the index view:

```
            <td><%= link_to 'Delete', attachment, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete, :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %></td>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Redirection is handled in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your attachment controller try:

```
  def destroy
    @attachment = Attachment.find(params[:id])
    @attachment.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to current_page_path }
    end
  end
```

Substitute your current page path in where I put **current_page_path**...

Comment: How would I handle the fact there are two different pages that allow you to delete the attachment?  Should I store the page url in flash?

Comment: I used this , :onclick =>  flash[:fromurl] = request.url